# Is there any way to treat the OpenVPN connected clients list as a hosts file or DNS source?

Tags: dns, openvpn

I would really like for clients on my VPN to be able to use the client names from the OpenVPN licenses as DNS names.  If, for example, my machine is connected with the client name `tgm-desktop` then I'd like to be able to use the DNS name `tgm-desktop` in pings and remote desktop calls from other client systems.

Comment: I'll admit that I wasn't aware of OpenVPN having "client names", or, even, licenses.

However, for *user names*, it might be possible to write a module for bind9 or another DNS server that would read the data from OpenVPN's `management` socket; however, I have not seen any such implementation yet.

In a system I manage, this (usernames in DNS) has been done by configuring the OpenVPN server to run a `client-connect` script that simply regenerates static zone files every time a client connects. (There are usually only 1-4 clients at a time, so the performance is okay.)

Comment: Certificates are named for each client, unless you allow using a single certificate multiple times.